# hibernate buildSessionFactory ClassFormatError:

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/InheritanceType

I got this error when try to build sessionFactory
my hibernate.cfg.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">mateusz</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mateusz123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carpool</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="org.mathew.data.User"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

my HibernateUtil class:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mathew.hibutil.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    at org.mathew.hibutil.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at org.mathew.mysql.MySqlQueries.<init>(MySqlQueries.java:16)
    at org.mathew.test.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/InheritanceType
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.extractInheritanceType(InheritanceState.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.<init>(InheritanceState.java:21)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.buildInheritanceStates(AnnotationBinder.java:2146)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processArtifactsOfType(AnnotationConfiguration.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1319)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:915)
    at org.mathew.hibutil.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 3 more
```

My libraries:

```
cglib
commons-collections
commons-logging
dom4j
hibernate3
hibernate-annotations
hibernate-commons-annotations
hibernate-core
java-api-6.0
javassist
jta
log4j
mysql-connector-java
persistence-api
slf4j
slf4j-log4j
```

I can't upload image :)

I would be thankfull if anybody can help.
THANKS! :)

Comment: Post you exact exception _and_ stacktrace for starters. But anyway, it looks like a dependency problem, with multiple versions of a jar on your classpath.

Comment: I added persistence-api dependency and the same error appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be managing your dependencies manually, you should really be using a dependency manager (maven, ivy with ant, etc.) to be sure you get the correct dependencies (all the libs *in their expected version*). Since you don't specify the versions of the libraries you're using, there are several possible problems:

- Incompatible version of persistence-api with hibernate
- Incompatible mix of hibernate jars: you apparently have a hibernate3 jar along with hibernate-core, that doesn't seem right. It looks like a old version of Hibernate mixed with more recent jars. So classes that only exist in the recent version might be accessing classes from the old one, if the jar comes first in the classpath.